# How to Remove google account from Mobile Programmatically

Tags: android, google-account

I want to remove google account on a button click from my app but i'm getting following security exception and the app crashes at this point.So please guide me if there is any possible way to do this.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10511 cannot remove accounts of type: com.google
```

Here is my code that i'm using

```
 public static void removeAccount(Context mContext){
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
        MainActivity activity;
        activity=(MainActivity)mContext;
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            Account accountToRemove = accounts[0];
            am.removeAccount(accountToRemove, null, null);
        }
    }
```

**Thankx in advance for any help.**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I also looking for this type of solution, please let me know if anybody figure out this thing